# Multiple api call in angular 4

Tags: angular

I've two API request.

`getActiveID` this will get me the activeID of each team. Each Team will have its own ID

`getActiveIDdetail` based on the activeID, I'll use this function to fetch details.

**App Component**

```
// Team date with it's unique ID    
public teamData = [
      { title: 'Team1', id: '22407' },
      { title: 'Team2', id: '21756' },
      { title: 'Team3', id: '18278' },
      { title: 'Team4', id: '21316' },
      { title: 'Team5', id: '8523' },
      { title: 'Team6', id: '21280' },
      { title: 'Team7', id: '18573' },
      { title: 'Team8', id: '22696' },
      { title: 'Team9', id: '21783' },
      { title: 'Team',  id: '20632' }
    ];

this.teamData.map(x => {
  if (x.id) {
    this.getActiveID(x.id);
  }
});

getActiveID(id) {
  this.service.getActiveID(id).subscribe(response => {
    const activeID = response.sprints.slice(-1)[0].id;
    this.getActiveIDdetail(activeID);
  });
}
```

**Service TS**

```
getActiveID(id: string) {
  return this.http.get<any>('/get-active-id/' + id);
}

getActiveIDdetail() {
  return this.http.get<any>('/get-active-id-detail/' + id);
}
```

Issue is, I've 10 teams so I'm making 10 http request and all these request are not sequence.

How do I combine all the response into single response, Also Please suggest me a better way to make http request?

Comment: `Issue is, I've 10 teams so I'm making 10 http request and all these request are not sequence.`, why do you care about sequence here? anyway, you can use forkJoin from rxjs `forkJoin()`whcih works similar to Promise.all

Comment: Why don't you use a `getAll()`?

Comment: With your http requests, a good thing would be to use a model instead of `any` and to externalize your api paths

Comment: Your `this.getActiveIDdetail(activeID);` is not doing anything inside the subscribe, whats the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this out? 
I didn't test the code, but I think it's going to work.

**App Component**

```
// Team date with it's unique ID    
public teamData = [
      { title: 'Team1', id: '22407' },
      { title: 'Team2', id: '21756' },
      { title: 'Team3', id: '18278' },
      { title: 'Team4', id: '21316' },
      { title: 'Team5', id: '8523' },
      { title: 'Team6', id: '21280' },
      { title: 'Team7', id: '18573' },
      { title: 'Team8', id: '22696' },
      { title: 'Team9', id: '21783' },
      { title: 'Team',  id: '20632' }
    ];

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.loadDetail(teamData).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

**Service**

```
loadDetail(teamData) {
  return Observable
    .from(teamData)
    .map(teamMember => teamMember.id)
    .mergeMap(this.getActiveID.bind(this))
    .mergeMap(this.getActiveIDdetail.bind(this))
    .combineAll(); 
}

getActiveID(id: string) {
  return this.http.get<any>('/get-active-id/' + id)
    .map(response => response.sprints.slice(-1)[0].id);
}

getActiveIDdetail(id: string) {
  return this.http.get<any>('/get-active-id-detail/' + id);
}
```